# AngularJS multilanguage URL routing with links

Tags: angularjs, multilingual

I have an AngularJS webapp. I´m changing the application so the URLs can be multilanguage (for SEO indexing purposes).

I´m setting up my app.js, like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/:language', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl'});     
    $routeProvider.when('/:language/about', {templateUrl: 'partials/about.html', controller: 'AboutCtrl'});
```

Then, in a service I get the language parameter with $routeParams and call my translation code with angular-translate to serve the page in the corresponding language.

Everything is working so far.

But now, all my internal links, i.e `<a href="/about">{{'ABOUT' | translate}}</a>` has stopped working, because they are missing the language parameter.

My approach, is to set the language in a service and get it to concatenate it in the links, something like `<a href="{{TranslationService.getLanguage()}}/about">{{'ABOUT' | translate}}</a>`. Of course, this will make me refactor all my links.

Is this the right approach or there is any better more clever one?

Comment: I did the same, but also added a $routeChangeStart listener which will set the $rootScope.language to the current locale. This way I can use a shorter {{ language }} to inject the language

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally followed my approach depicted above. Using UI-Router probably is best approach, but the change had a medium/big impact on my development.

Comment: this shouldn't be an accepted answer since it doesn't provide the solution to this question. You should either improve it or delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) plugin and define your routes as nested.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-routing-for-nested-states

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
     url: '/:language',
     ...
  })
  .state('home.about', {
     url: '/about',
     ...
  });
```

Then, you can use [ui-sref](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref) directive and navigate the routes with relative path.

`home.html`: To go to a 'About' child route `<a ui-sref=".about">About</a>`

`about.html`: To go to a parent route `<a ui-sref="^">Home</a>`